# Suddenly SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE error in Firefox 99.0.1, but not in other browsers nor a different profile in same FF Version

Tags: firefox, browser, ssl

Out of the blue (presumably with the last update to 99.0.1), a website I use a lot doesn't open anymore but shows

```
An error occurred during a connection to $fqdn. 
Peer’s Certificate has been revoked.

Error code: SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE
```

Unfortunately it's an Intranet site so you can't verify this yourself, but it has a valid certificate from "issuer: C=BM; O=QuoVadis Limited; CN=QuoVadis Global SSL ICA G3" and it works fine in everything else on my Mac (21.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0: Wed Jan  5 21:37:58 PST 2022; root:xnu-8019.80.24~20/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64): Safari, Chrome, curl, you name it - no issues.

I then got curious and found that it also works if I create a new profile in Firefox. Poking around more, it seems like when using my old profile, and any combination of OCSP settings, it at some point finds that the certificate is in a blocklist:

#### old profile, using ./firefox-bin --MOZ_LOG="certverifier:5,pipnss:4"

```
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: IsChainValid
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: Top of CheckRevocation
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Get(171bacea0,"firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") not in cache
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no cached OCSP response
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: Top of CheckRevocation
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain::CheckRevocation: checking CRLite
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain::CheckCRLite: CRLite check returned state=2
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no stapled OCSP response
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Get(171bad6f0,"firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") not in cache
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no cached OCSP response
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss SSLServerCertVerificationResult::Run setting NEW cert
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13f0861a0] nsNSSSocketInfo::NoteTimeUntilReady
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss CanFalseStartCallback [13f085fc0] ok
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13f085fc0] HandshakeCallback: succeeded using TLS version range (0x0301,0x0304)
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss HandshakeCallback KEEPING existing cert
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13f0861a0] nsNSSSocketInfo::SetHandshakeCompleted
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13eb96c00] starting AuthCertificateHookInternal
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/pipnss [13eb96c00] SSLServerCertVerificationJob::Run
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier Top of VerifyCert
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: IsChainValid
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: IsChainValid
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: IsChainValid
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: Top of CheckRevocation
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Get(171bac650,"firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") not in cache
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no cached OCSP response
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: Top of CheckRevocation
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Get(171bacea0,"firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") not in cache
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no cached OCSP response
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: Top of CheckRevocation
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain::CheckRevocation: checking CRLite
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain::CheckCRLite: CRLite check returned state=2
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no stapled OCSP response
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Get(171bad6f0,"firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") not in cache
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no cached OCSP response
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss SSLServerCertVerificationResult::Run setting NEW cert
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13c5f2770] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: using TLS version range (0x0301,0x0304)
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13c5f2770] Socket set up
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13c5f2770] connecting SSL socket
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: E/pipnss [13c5f2770] Lower layer connect error: -5934
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13c6c86a0] starting AuthCertificateHook
[Parent 13539: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13c6c86a0] starting AuthCertificateHookInternal
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/pipnss [13c6c86a0] SSLServerCertVerificationJob::Run
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier Top of VerifyCert
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: certificate is in blocklist
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: certificate is in blocklist
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: certificate is in blocklist
[Parent 13539: SSL Cert #1]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: certificate is in blocklist
```

In a new profile, there's also some errors and stuff I don't quite understand, but it works anyways:

#### newly created profile, using ./firefox-bin --MOZ_LOG="certverifier:5,pipnss:4"

```
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: E/pipnss [13a70f520] Lower layer connect error: -5934
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13a70f8b0] starting AuthCertificateHook
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13a70f8b0] starting AuthCertificateHookInternal
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/pipnss [13a70f8b0] SSLServerCertVerificationJob::Run
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier Top of VerifyCert
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: CheckSignatureDigestAlgorithm
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: IsChainValid
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: Top of CheckRevocation
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Get(172b38ea0,"firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") not in cache
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no cached OCSP response
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: Top of CheckRevocation
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain::CheckRevocation: checking CRLite
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain::CheckCRLite: CRLite check returned state=2
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no stapled OCSP response
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Get(172b396f0,"firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") not in cache
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: no cached OCSP response
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/pipnss DoOCSPRequest to 'http://ocsp.quovadisglobal.com'
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier OCSPCache::Put(172b396f0, "firstPartyDomain: , partitionKey: ") added to cache
[Parent 13639: SSL Cert #4]: D/certverifier NSSCertDBTrustDomain: returning SECSuccess after OCSP request failure
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss SSLServerCertVerificationResult::Run setting NEW cert
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13a70f8b0] HandshakeCallback: succeeded using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0304)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss HandshakeCallback KEEPING existing cert
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13a70f520] nsNSSSocketInfo::NoteTimeUntilReady
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [13a70f520] nsNSSSocketInfo::SetHandshakeCompleted
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1280bde10] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: range.max limited to 1.2 due to BE_CONSERVATIVE flag
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1280bde10] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0303)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1280bde10] Socket set up
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1280bde10] connecting SSL socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: E/pipnss [1280bde10] Lower layer connect error: -5934
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [128309030] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: range.max limited to 1.2 due to BE_CONSERVATIVE flag
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [128309030] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0303)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [128309030] Socket set up
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [128309030] connecting SSL socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: E/pipnss [128309030] Lower layer connect error: -5934
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [139ebc100] Shutting down socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [138c0ed10] Shutting down socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [139ebdde0] Shutting down socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [139ebd9c0] Shutting down socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1283096c0] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: range.max limited to 1.2 due to BE_CONSERVATIVE flag
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1283096c0] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0303)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1283096c0] Socket set up
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1283096c0] connecting SSL socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: E/pipnss [1283096c0] Lower layer connect error: -5934
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [109b6af50] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: range.max limited to 1.2 due to BE_CONSERVATIVE flag
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [109b6af50] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0303)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [109b6af50] Socket set up
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [109b6af50] connecting SSL socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: E/pipnss [109b6af50] Lower layer connect error: -5934
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [12830a2f0] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: range.max limited to 1.2 due to BE_CONSERVATIVE flag
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [12830a2f0] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0303)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [12830a2f0] Socket set up
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [12830a2f0] connecting SSL socket
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: E/pipnss [12830a2f0] Lower layer connect error: -5934
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [1283097e0] HandshakeCallback: succeeded using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0303)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [109b6af50] nsNSSSocketInfo::NoteTimeUntilReady
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [109b6af50] nsNSSSocketInfo::SetHandshakeCompleted
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [12830a860] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: range.max limited to 1.2 due to BE_CONSERVATIVE flag
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [12830a860] nsSSLIOLayerSetOptions: using TLS version range (0x0303,0x0303)
[Parent 13639: Socket Thread]: D/pipnss [12830a860] Socket set up
```

I'm trying to understand where this blocklist is... there are plenty of blocklisty-things for malicious content, addons, etc., but I really didn't find anything like a "TLS blocklist". I also tried to use cert9.db from a pristine profile, didn't help. Looking at the code [I see the line where it happens](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/4b3039b48c3cb67774270ebcc2a7d8624d888092/security/certverifier/NSSCertDBTrustDomain.cpp#L419), but between all the OCSP, stapling, CRL checking etc. I don't really understand enough to see where it goes wrong.

Any hints how I can locate this blocklist and maybe find how my site got in there?

Comment: Doesn’t matter if the certificate is valid or expired if it’s been revoked. Have you deleted the certificate out of the Firefox certificate store? This will allow to create a new certificate exception.  The creation of a new profile suggests this solution will work